# Mount can't find device in /etc/fstab

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount

It is my second day on Linux. I am having difficulties mounting an USB drive. It shows this error:

```
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1/mnt in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: How do you mount?

Comment: sudo mount /dev/sdb1/mnt

Comment: This is wrong. You should mount your device on a mountpoint. for example: `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb`. Just remember that the `/media/usb/` should be made before mounting

Comment: for USB, it is better it be mounted inside `/media/` folder. moreover, `/mnt/` is not made by you. it is built-in folder in ubuntu

Comment: I created a directory named "media" and a subdirectory "usb"under media.Then i tried mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb.. But it still have the problem : can't find /dev/sdb1/media/usb in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: You have made this `media` in your home directory while we are talking about root directory (/). Run this first `sudo mkdir /media/usb` then mount your USB by `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Why this error?

**You probably forgot to tell `mount` where to mount your drive.**

Linux uses device files (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb1`, etc.). And unlike Windows drives (`C:`, `D:`, etc.), you cannot access them directly (`cd /dev/sdb1` will inevitably fail, telling you that it is not a directory but a file). If you want to open a drive with `mount`, you need to provide a **mountpoint**. A mountpoint is a directory wherein your USB drive will be opened and where you will be able to access your files.

---

### Solution

1. Create a  directory that you will use as the mountpoint for your drive:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/mydrive
   ```
2. Mount your drive with this command:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydrive
   ```

   ***Note:*** If you don't know your drive's device file, you can run `sudo fdisk -l` or `lsblk` to identify the partition you're looking for.
3. Now if you run `ls /mnt/mydrive`, it should list your drive's files.
4. When you're done, don't forget to **unmount** your USB drive before removing it from the computer:

   ```
   umount /dev/sdb1
   ```

---

### More information about this error

`/etc/fstab` is a file in which you can associate a partition with a mountpoint, allowing you to run `mount <device>` instead of `mount <device> <mountpoint>`. **This is why you get this confusing error.**

*fstab* has many more uses like mounting a partition at boot time, etc. [More information about *fstab* on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab)

Answer (score 1):

To know your device name use `sudo fdisk`. Your device can be recognized by its size, and probably looks like `/dev/sdx`, where `x` could be any letter from a to z. (Usually a is assigned to your first internal hard-drive)

To mount a usb drive `sudo mount <Your Device Name>  <Mount Position>`, for example:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

To access what you have just mounted use the position where you have mounted. In the above example I have used `/mnt`, so I would type:

```
cd /mnt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/spider 
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/spider
```

Remember to replace the drives name from /dev/sda2 to yours. You can find the name of your drives by using the command sudo fdisk -l .

Answer (score 0):

maybe this has been answered, I've been trying to figure it out and finally got my virtual drive mounted back into wsl after a rebuild of Windows.

i move into the directory with the "ext4.vhdx" file, and my distro was set to default. Then this command, fixed it right up.

wsl mount --source c: --target /mnt/c  .\ext4.vhdx -a