# USB drive for macOSX made with dd doesn't work and now can't be used for anything

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, mount

I bought a new USB drive and I tried to burn to it the mac os x 10.13.02 using `dd`:

Unmounted the drive

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Burned the iso:

```
dd if="myfile.iso" of="/dev/sdb1"
```

After this I tried to restart and boot from flash, but it didn't work and the USB is corrupted - I can't access the files

When I try to mount it I get:

```
mz@mz-32:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for mz: 
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a Mac computer? in a Mac OS? -- How is Ubuntu involved in your problem?

Comment: I think OP wanted to make bootable USB of Mac OS ISO?

Comment: Try mounting to a specific folder. `sudo mkdir /media/usb && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting usb drive error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771473/mounting-usb-drive-error)

Comment: i try download the mac iso file  i have ubuntu 17.10

Comment: i try this command:<br>`mz@mz-32:~$ sudo mkdir /media/usb && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
[sudo] password for mz: 
mount: /media/usb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Comment: do you have the libraries for the Mac file system installed?

Answer (score 1):

### Clone from a hybrid iso file to a USB pendrive in Ubuntu

I suggest the following steps to clone from a hybrid iso file to a USB pendrive in Ubuntu. Most linux iso files are [hybrid iso files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid), but I don't know about MacOS iso files.

If the MacOS iso file is not a hybrid iso file, the cloning process will not create a working USB boot drive, and you have to use some kind of extraction method. I don't know any extraction tool for this purpose. If necessary, ask at a Mac forum to learn about it.

- Check with `md5sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly. See this link,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)
- Clone with a cloning tool.

  - **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` and **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)** are GUI tools with a final checkpoint and help to identify the target device (usually a USB pendrive), which makes them relatively safe.
  - **`dd`** is a powerful command line tool, which is dangerous because it does what you tell it to do without any question. Double-check carefully and it will work, if you use a command line like this,

    ```
    sudo dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4096
    ```

    where x is the device letter of the target drive. It is very important that you get it right (replace x with the correct letter), otherwise you might overwrite (and destroy) valuable data.

    Please notice that you should clone to the whole device, starting at the head end, not to a partition, so there should be a letter (but no digit).