# mount samba share gives 'can't find [mount path] in /etc/fstab'

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o  //192.168.0.3/Public /media/external
mount: /media/external: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

The path `/media/external` exists and is empty. If I do `smbclient //192.168.0.3/Public` I can see the files perfectly.

What is wrong? It seems like a local error because the error is immediate

[Mount can't find device in /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771473/mount-cant-find-device-in-etc-fstab) was not useful

Comment: Leave out the `-o`. The mount command expects some options, you don't give them in your command, so it tries to look them up in `/etc/fstab` where they don't exist either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included the `-o` (for `option`) flag, but did not specify any options.

The `mount` command then tries to get additional information from the `/etc/fstab` table. However, that file doesn't have a line with the same Samba share, so it can't find the options and complains.

Either specify an option on the command line, or leave out the `-o` flag altogether.